# How to update max value of Radial Progress Chart

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm using [Radial Progress Chart and](http://pablomolnar.github.io/radial-progress-chart/) and want to update max value of chart but i can't implement successfully..

I'm doing like this -

```
radialChart.update({max: 100});
radialChart.update({[max: 100]});
radialChart.update({series:[{max: 100}]});
```

Is there any other method, i update the chart max value

I'm not familiar with d3.js

Thanks

Comment: I just edited a codepen to see setting max value https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpOqLR and i am able to set it

Comment: i need to update max value after initialize chart

Answer (score 0):

I just checked radial progress chart source code at a high level. i didn't find logic that updates max value after a chart is rendered.   (I didn't go through it completely. Please correct me if I haven't looked at it completely)
As a workaround, I had to remove the svg and then redraw it.

Take a look at the below codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpOqLR

```
d3.select(".main").selectAll("*").remove();
```

Above code helps to remove svg completely and then I drew the graph with new max value.